# How to check whether internet is active (checking both network availability & webpage accessibility) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, connectivity

I am currently working in an iOS project where I need to check whether my phone is connected to the internet (mobile data/wifi) or not. I'm using reachability class which only check network connection availability but suppose a scenario where there is no balance in my phone. In that case I wouldn't able to access internet but still reachability shows me that internet is reachable via mobile network as data connection is on although I can't access the page.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx)

Comment: I'm sick of this topic.  Run a search, silly.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check using connection:didReceiveResponse:

```
        NSString *urlString=@"yourUrl";
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLConnection *connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];

        -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
        {
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
        [connection cancel];
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        int code = (int)[httpResponse statusCode];
        if (code == 200) {
            NSLog(@"File exists");
        }
        else if(code == 404)
        {
            NSLog(@"File not exist");
        }
        }
        -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
        {
        NSLog(@"File not exist");
        }
```

Comment: I have checked keeping my mobile data on even though there is no balance .So it should print "File not exist" . It prints but take long time . How can I reduce the response time or set time-interval like 5 sec. & if that period is over then how I can check that?

Comment: When you create NSURLRequest you can provide timeoutInterval .                                              NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy  
               timeoutInterval:5.0];

Answer (score 1):

Another example would be if you're improperly connected to a Wifi network - your phone has a good connection but no permission to access any pages on the Internet.

In this case, the only method of detection would be to try and send a web request to a reliable site (say www.google.com). If your request to this source times out after a set amount of time (say five seconds) then you can safely conclude that the phone has connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the internet connection

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
//Manual timeout of 20 seconds
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 20];
if (data)
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the Internet");
else
    NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the Internet");
```

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx)